# Domain in a Surjective Function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, terminology

We all know that the definition of Surjective functions as follows:

if for every element $y$  in the codomain $Y$ of $f$ there is at least one element $x$ in the domain $X$ of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)

This is the same definition everywhere else.

**Now my question is:**
Is it also necessary in an Onto/Surjective Function that every single element in the domain has to be mapped to an element in the codomain.

Or can we have unmapped elements in the domain?

I am studying discreet mathematics on my own, with just books to guide me. So I apologise for before if this question sounds silly. But appreciate any help on this nonetheless.

Comment: It is necessary for *any* function. Each element in the domain must be mapped to an element in the codomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element in the domain has to be mapped to an element in the codomain for a **function**, in this particular case, a surjective function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, wheteher a function is surjective or not is about the 'output' side of the function ... it has nothing to do with what happens on the 'input' side.

Second, while many people insist that functions map every element from its domain to a member in its co-domain, sometimes it is handy to have  [*partial* functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), where this is not the case. Thus, a function that *does* map every element from its domain would be called a 'total' function, while a function that does not map every element from its domain would be a 'partial' function.

Again, many people will insist that functions be total, and say that 'function' is synonimous with 'total function'. However, allowing functions to be partial affords a number of conceptual advantages over insisting that functions always be total functions:

1. It allows for a distinction between what one might call a 'domain of discourse' (the set of objects under consideration, which is typically a nice set/structure like the natural numbers or real numbers) and a 'domain of definition' (the subset for which the function is actually defined). This would also greatly help those pesky 'what is the domain of this function' questions, where one often has to guess what *kinds* of objects (i.e. what structure?) the function is restricted to in the first place: if we could just say 'the domain of discourse of this function is the real numbers .. now find the domain of definition', that problem would be solved immediately.
2. This distinction on the 'input side' of the function nicely mirrors the distinction between 'co-domain' and 'range' on the 'output side'. Indeed, as such, just as functions can be onto (surjective, or right-total) or not, functions can be left-total or not. You yourself were wondering about this very possibility.
3. This distinction would also nicely mirror how we talk about binary relations, which can be 'left-total' or not, just as much as they can 'right-total' or not. In fact, we call binary relations 'functional' as soon as they are 'right-unique', so a 'functional' relation need not be left-total. It would therefore make rhetorical sense if a function need not be left-total either.
4. The word 'co-domain' is most likely short for 'converse domain'. Russell defined the 'converse domain' of a function/binary relation as the domain of its converse (better known as inverse). But if the function is not surjective, then when we insist that the 'domain' is only those objects for which the function is defined, it follows that the 'converse domain' should be the *range* of the original function, rather than its 'co-domain': weird! However, by having a domain of discourse separate from a domain of definition, the 'co-domain' simply becomes the 'domain of discourse' of the converse, and the 'range' is what one could regard as the 'domain of definition' of the converse. Nice, symmetric, logical: not weird!

So ... yeah ... good question: why do so many people insist that functions not have unmapped elements in its domain?!